# Aplicativo fecha ao abrir activity

Tags: android, xml, android-activity

O aplicativo simplesmente fecha quando pressiono o `TextView`.

Ele deveria passar para outra `Activity`.

Já tentei de várias formas e continua travando.

```
package com.example.evellyn.auris;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListOfEpisodesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_episodes);

        TextView episode1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.episode1);
        episode1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent playEpisode = new Intent(ListOfEpisodesActivity.this,PlayingEpisodeActivity.class);
                startActivity(playEpisode);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Aqui está o código xml da Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.evellyn.auris.ListOfEpisodesActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagemPodcast"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nossalingua"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/imagemPodcast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:src="@drawable/example"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/episode1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/nossaLinguaEp1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/example"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/nossaLinguaEp2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Adicionou a **PlayingEpisodeActivity** no AndroidManifest?  Exibe algum erro no **Logcat**  do AndroidStudio?

Comment: tá dando fatal Exception
outOfMemory

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta e colocar o Stack que está sendo exibido? Fica mais fácil pra ajudar! =)

Comment: acabei de resolver

Answer (score 1):

O problema foi resolvido usando android:largeHeap="true" no manifest